# immutable js map get deep map objects

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, immutable.js

I have an Immutable Map from connected react router in redux state.

```
router: {
    location: {
      pathname: '/test',
      search: '',
      hash: '',
      state: {
        tokenIds: {
          size: 2,
          _map: {
            size: 2,
            _root: {
              ownerID: {},
              entries: [
                [
                  '70c48738',
                  true
                ],
                [
                  '1a8a6c24',
                  true
                ]
              ]
            },
            __altered: false
          }
        }
      },
      key: 'rkh3ve'
    },
    action: 'POP'
  }
```

I want to extract tokenIds array. I am expecting something like 
`[70c48738,1a8a6c24]`.

I tried `state.getIn(['router','location','state','tokenIds')` but result I am getting is

```
Map {size: 3, _root: ArrayMapNode, __ownerID: undefined, __hash: undefined, __altered: false}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's how ImmutableJS works. By calling `state.getIn(['router','location','state','tokenIds'])` you are accessing ImmutableJS `Map` instance and it is not just a JS `Map` or JS object. You still need to process it to get what you want. Check [documentation on Map](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map) to see how to access the actual data.

To achieve what you expect, you could, for example, do: `state.getIn(['router','location','state','tokenIds']).keySeq().toJS()` - this would return regular JS array of `Map` keys. Or without `toJS()` to get ImmutableJS `Array` instance.